# Create multiple users in Postgres container using initdb script

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have the following Docker Compose stack:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    secrets:
      - pg_user_secret
      - pg_password_secret
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER_FILE: /run/secrets/pg_user_secret
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/pg_password_secret
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  adminer:
    image: adminer:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

volumes:
  postgres-data:

secrets:
  pg_user_secret:
    file: './pg_user.txt'
  pg_password_secret:
    file: './pg_password.txt'x
```

I am trying to create 3 databases and 3 users at initialization with the following script `init.sql`:

```
CREATE USER authUser WITH PASSWORD 'authPassword';
CREATE USER portfoliosUser WITH PASSWORD 'portfoliosPassword';
CREATE USER ordersUser WITH PASSWORD 'ordersPassword';

CREATE DATABASE auth;
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE auth FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE auth TO authUser;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE auth to authUser;

CREATE DATABASE portfolios;
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE portfolios FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE portfolios TO authUser;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE portfolios TO portfoliosUser;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE portfolios to authUser;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE portfolios to portfoliosUser;

CREATE DATABASE orders;
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE orders FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE orders TO ordersUser;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE orders to ordersUser;
```

But whenever I try to connect to postgres with one of the users created in the script I get the error: `Role X does not exist.`. What can be the cause of this behavior?

UPDATE: Actually the problem was with the name formatting, by default postgres converts strings to lowercase, so `authUser` will actually be saved as `authuser`.

Comment: [This script (`bitbucket.org`)](https://bitbucket.org/turing85/uber-docker-compose/src/master/localdeployment/postgres/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-multiple-postgresql-databases.sh) might help. An example usage can be found [here (`bitbucket.org`)](https://bitbucket.org/turing85/uber-docker-compose/src/0fcc6e7fa1a8796c5a417730cc9029a6a9cea0a1/localdeployment/docker-compose.yml#lines-4).